# PSTricks: Improving picture quality

Tags: pstricks, svg

I'm trying to draw smooth curves with variable width using PSTriks. The results I'm getting don't have the quality I need. For example, from this piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
    \pscurve[variableLW,startLW=1pt,endLW=20pt]%
   (-1,0.5)(-2,1)(2,2)(-1,-2)(2,-2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

that I got from the documentation, I get the following:
[image: result]

As you can see, it has a few blank spaces. How can I avoid that?

Note: I need the output to be SVG, so to compile the code I'm doing:

```
latex file.tex 
dvips file.dvi
inkscape file.ps --export-plain-svg=file.svg
```

UPDATE: I'm new to this, and I forgot to check the .ps, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether the DVI is working? If it doesn't have the problems it's an Inkscape bug.

Comment: Does the postscript file also have the same problem? If not, it might be an inkscape problem, and probably offtopic here.

Comment: If I compile with xelatex, the resulting pdf also shown blank spaces, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I can't say who is the culprit: After latex, dvips, and ps2pdf, the PDF viewed with evince (some document viewer) looks fine, but in all other combinations (ps viewed with ghostview, evince or okular, pdf viewed with ghostview or okular) the image is scrambled, like the second picture above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the example only with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`.  There are some problems
mith `xelatex`:

or use package `auto-pst-pdf` and run `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\pscurve[variableLW,startLW=1pt,endLW=20pt]%
    (-1,0.5)(-2,1)(2,2)(-1,-2)(2,-2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
inkscape --without-gui --file=PSTricks.pdf --export-plain-svg=PSTricks.svg
```

works also very well.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this solves the problem. I used this chain, and the result depends on the viewer. The image looks like yours only for one viewer, but not for the other two. And none of the viewers was able to display the ps file correctly, whatever correct means.

Comment: the `ps` file is not of interest here. Use the `pdf` file.

Comment: To me it is unclear what the contents of the image really is, if it displays differently for various combinations of viewers and file formats. In fact, if it's a majority vote, than the meaning of the pstricks code is the second scrambled image. Is it clear that the code in the ps/pdf file is ok and all the viewers are buggy?

Comment: The pdf file looks fine, so thank you very much for that. However, the svg file still shows blank spaces; I guess that means it's a inkscape problem and that it's offtopic, but if you someone knows a way to fix it I would appreciate it.

Comment: @JenniferHurtado: I have no idea what inkscape does. However, if you need it only for one image, then take a screenshot, save it in the `pnm` format and create with `potrace` a vector image file which has only the contour and convert it to svg.